# Power Query: Splitting Multi-Level Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

I have the following source data:

[image: Source data]

I am trying to determine the needed transformations to obtain the following desired result:

[image: Desired result]

The source data has a hierarchy of data in the cells of **Col2**. I would like to keep data at the first hierarchy level in **Col2**, and I would like to create separate columns (**Col2.1**, **Col2.2**, ..., **Col2.N**) for the second and subsequent hierarchy levels.

The individual values in the cell are separated by a line feed (**#(lf)**), and a given value's hierarchy level is determined by its indentation level (each indentation level is represented by three space characters).

A given value's parent in the hierarchy is determined by order. For example, `String1.2` is at the second indentation level. Based solely on indentation level, it could therefore be placed hierarchically under either `String1` or `String2`. However, since it appears after `String1` and before `String2`, it must be placed hierarchically under `String1`.

Note that the **String*** names I've chosen are sanitized names and were picked to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. My actual data has no predictable leading prefixes and does not imply a hierarchy by its lexical content. So, the splitting logic must not be based on the values themselves. It must be based on only a value's indentation level and order relative to other values and their indentation levels.

Here is the M Language code I have so far:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Col2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Col2")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

This M Language code produces this actual result:

[image: Actual result]

Additional examples of source data / desired results are shown next.

**Example 1 Source Data**
[image: Source 1]

**Example 1 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 1]

**Example 2 Source Data**
[image: Source 2]

**Example 2 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 2]

**Example 3 Source Data**
[image: Source 3]

**Example 3 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 3]

**Example 4 Source Data**
[image: Source 4]

**Example 4 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 4]

**Example 5 Source Data**
[image: Source 5]

**Example 5 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 5]

**Example 6 Source Data**
[image: Source 6]

**Example 6 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 6]

**Example 7 Source Data**
[image: Source 7]

**Example 7 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 7]

**Example 8 Source Data**
[image: Source 8]

**Example 8 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 8]

**Example 9 Source Data**
[image: Source 9]

**Example 9 Desired Result**
[image: Desired 9]

**Example 9 Actual Result**
[image: Actual 9]

What additional applied steps must I add to my M Language code to transform the given source data examples to the desired results shown above?

Comment: Does `String1` need to be repeated in Col2?  Or can `String2` appear directly below `String1` with a blank row3?

Comment: Hi Ron, sorry for the delayed reply. I have been out of town. Yes, string 1 does need to be repeated in column 2. I will attempt to elaborate further in either the comments to the answer you gave or by updating my original post. Thank you for your time in making a quite in-depth reply in your answer!

Comment: Still working on it but deleted my answer for now since it is showing errors. Will repost when I get it figured out.

Comment: Ron, wow, I can't thank you enough for the effort you're putting into this. It is very kind of you and is much appreciated. This is not a problem I would have gotten by on my own. I will edit my post to make it a little cleaner for future reference. No functional or substantive changes, though I will add a couple more examples (nothing new or surprising, just a couple of edge cases). Mainly just trying to improve readability and completeness... Thank you again.

Comment: Let me finish the code for the special cases I came up with. Then you can perhaps give me an idea of what `Col1` represents and I will either give you some ideas or suggest posting a different question. As an initial thought, you may be able to simply use `Table.Join` to add on the other columns.

Comment: Ron, will do, thank you. When I see your new code, I'll give it a go (I'm sure it will be fine), and then we can discuss further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited in accordance with your updated problem statements.***

***M Code***

```
let
    #"Table to Process" = "Table" & Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_to_Process"]}[Content][Column1]{0},

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=#"Table to Process"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}}),

//Special Case: Replace Nulls in Col1
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null," ",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Col1"}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Segments", 
        each try Text.Split([Col2],"#(lf)") 
             otherwise null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Col2"}),
    #"Expanded Segments" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Segments"),
 
//Determine Column by number of spaces at the start of each Segment name
//Add Offset Col to determine the row
// Trim the Segments
    #"Add Col" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Segments", "Col", each (Text.Length([Segments]) - Text.Length(Text.TrimStart([Segments]))) / 3 ?? 0),
    #"Add Offset Col" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Add Col") &
            {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Add Col"[Col])},
            type table[Col1=text, Segments=text,Col=Int64.Type, Offset Col=Int64.Type]),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Add Offset Col",{{"Segments", Text.Trim, type text}}),

//Determine Row
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Add Row" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Row", each 
        if [Offset Col] = null or [Offset Col] >= [Col] 
        then [Index] else null, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Row",{"Offset Col", "Index"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns1",{"Row"}),

//Column Names for Segments
    cn = List.Transform(List.Numbers(0, List.Max(#"Filled Down"[Col])+1), each 
            if _ = 0 then "Col2" 
            else Number.ToText(_,"'Col2.'0")),

//Group by Row
    #"Group Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down",{"Row"},{
        {"rw", (t)=>
            let 
                rr = Table.RemoveColumns(t,"Row"),
                colNames = Table.TransformColumns(rr,{
                    {"Col", each if _ = 0 
                                 then "Col2" 
                                 else Number.ToText(_,"'Col2.'0"), 
                                 type text}}),
                #"Convert to Row" = Record.FromList(colNames[Segments],colNames[Col]),
                #"First Col" = Record.ReorderFields(
                        Record.AddField(#"Convert to Row","Col1",colNames[Col1]{0}),{"Col1"} & cn,2)
            in 
               #"First Col", type record}
        }),
    #"Removed Row Index" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group Rows",{"Row"}),
   
    //Fill in the blank entries
    #"Offset Columns Count" = Table.RowCount(#"Removed Row Index")-1,
    #"Add Offset rws" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            List.Accumulate(
                List.Numbers(1,#"Offset Columns Count"),
                Table.ToColumns(#"Removed Row Index"),
                (s,c)=> s &
                    {List.Repeat({null},c) & List.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Row Index"[rw],c)})),
    
    #"Fill Nulls" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Offset rws", "Fill in Nulls", each 
        let 
            L = Record.ToList([Column1]),
            lastNonNull = List.PositionOfAny(L,List.Select(L,each _ <> null),Occurrence.Last),
            nullPos = List.PositionOfAny(L,List.Select(L,each _ = null),Occurrence.All),
            nullPosToFill = List.Select(nullPos, each _ < lastNonNull),
            fillCol = List.Accumulate(nullPosToFill,{},(s,c)=> s & {Record.FieldNames([Column1]){c}}),

            fillRec = List.Accumulate(fillCol,[Column1],(s,c)=>
                    Record.TransformFields(s, {c,(x)=> 
                        if Record.Field([Column2],c) <> null 
                            then Record.Field([Column2],c) 
                        else if Record.Field([Column3],c) <> null 
                            then Record.Field([Column3],c)
                        else if Record.Field([Column4],c) <> null 
                            then Record.Field([Column4],c) 
                        else null 
                    }) 
            )
        in 
            fillRec, type record),

    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Fill Nulls",List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Fill Nulls"), each Text.StartsWith(_,"Column"))),
    #"Expanded Fill in Nulls" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Fill in Nulls", {"Col1"} & cn ),

//Set data types to text
    #"Type As Text" = 
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Fill in Nulls", 
            List.Transform({"Col1"} & cn, each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Type As Text"
```

***Data Sample***
[image]

***Result***
[image]

Comment: In the result you give, `String1.2` is shown as being hierarchically under `String2`. However, that is not the case. As its name implies, and as its indentation level dictates, it belongs hierarchically under `String1`.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I may be beginning to understand your point about indentation level being the only determiner of hierarchy level... More comments to follow...

Comment: In addition to the indentation level, the order of the items in the cell being split matters. If an item is at a **higher** indentation level than `String1` and nothing else has yet appeared at the **same** indentation level as `String1`, that item needs to be paired with `String1`. This is why `String1.2` must be paired with `String1` and must not be paired with `String2`. I will update my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Ron, I've just posted an update to my question to try to address your question. Does this adequately answer the question, or is further clarification needed?

Comment: @Dave Yes. But I haven't had a chance to look at the code yet. Will do that later.

Comment: @Dave Please give the above modified code a try.

Comment: Ron, I think we had a race condition. I was producing examples from code taken just before you updated your answer! It appears that one of my counterexamples is fixed but that the other three aren't quite there yet. I must say, this is some impressive work you're doing! I just can't seem to grasp M well enough yet, but hopefully with time I'll get there.

Comment: @Dave The code I have just provided seems to work on all of the examples you provided. It still needs some modifications for examples I can think of which you did not provide, but I want to ensure that this algorithm is working on what we have. As anticipated, filling in the "blanks" was the difficult part.

Comment: Ron, yes, this code works properly on all of the examples I provided. I'm going to add one more, but it's just for completeness since it's an edge case your code is working fine on. I'll be on the lookout for updated code that handles the test cases you mentioned having thought of but which didn't occur to me to provide.

Comment: Hi Ron, please see the notes for you that I just added to the end of my original post.

Comment: Ron, I just found a mainline case that's not quite right. I'll post it as example 9 shortly. I realize the updates you're currently working on may make this moot, but I'll put it out there to be safe.

Comment: @Dave Yes, the new code will handle that example. It already does, but there's another case that it doesn't yet work on.

Comment: @Dave I've edited to supply code which handles all of your examples, as well as some cases you haven't posted. I'm not satisfied as the `fillRec` step within `#"fillNulls"` uses hard coded references (and a fixed number of them). However, with the correct number of `if...then...else if` clauses it should be OK, but converting it to a dynamic method is proving troublesome. I suggest to work with this for now and let's see how it goes.

Comment: Ron, yes, confirmed working on all test cases. I agree, further pursuit of a fully general solution is not necessary. The code you have provided goes at least as deep as my application needs. As mentioned elsewhere, I'll be off the task related to this post until next week. I'm going to ahead and accept this exceptional answer. I may touch base with you later if I have any trouble integrating into my application (your time and inclination permitting, of course). Again, I can't thank you enough for the generosity you've shown with your time and expertise. *Thank you!*